# Prove $\tan x\sec x= \sin^3x \sec^2x +\sin x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Can you help me prove the identity $$\tan x\sec x= \sin^3x \sec^2x +\sin x$$
I began working on the left side and changed everything to sine and cosine terms.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that: $\sin^{2}+\cos^{2} x=1$. Note that 
$$\begin{align}
\sin^{3}x\sec^{2}x+\sin x&=\sin^{3}x\frac{1}{\cos^{2}x}+\sin x \\ 
&=\frac{\sin^{3}x+\sin x\cos^{2} x}{\cos^{2} x}=\frac{\sin x(\sin^{2}+\cos^{2} x)}{\cos^{2} x}\\
&=\frac{\sin x}{\cos^{2} x}\\
&=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\frac{1}{\cos x}\\
&=\tan x\sec x
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$  in the right to get $\sin x \sec^2 x (1 - \cos^2 x) + \sin x$. You can take it from here...

Answer (score 0):

Also $$\tan{x}\sec{x}=\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos{x}}=\sin{x}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos^2{x}}=\sin{x}\sec^2{x}=\sin{x}(1+\tan^2{x})=$$

$$=\sin{x}(1+\tan^2{x})=\sin{x}\left(1+\frac{\sin^2{x}}{\cos^2{x}}\right)=\sin{x}+\frac{\sin^3{x}}{\cos^2{x}}=\sin{x}+\sin^3{x}\sec^2{x}$$